# why use blob field for php serialized object

Tags: php, mysql

I was reading somewhere the it is recommended to use BLOB field type instead of CHAR to store serialized objects in PHP. Is it true? Why?

Comment: Where did you read this and what were the arguments? Anyway, I think this is too subjective for SO

Comment: The only thing I can think of, off the top of my head is size and not worrying about cutting off a serialized object due to a field limit. Other than that, BLOBs are stored outside of a MySQL table in their own file per row - not sure if that is better than a char/varchar that is stored inline with the rest of the table though.

Comment: Blobs are also binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Session data is structured according to a set of rules defined by PHP and therefore should be opaque to the DBMS

2) (as Fluffeh has hinted at) CHAR fields are intended for holding small pieces of data and often have an upper limit on their size. Data will be truncated

3) Even where any limit is greater than the known maximum size of a session, a CHAR field has a constant footprint regardless of the amount of data it conatins (unlike a VARCHAR field) so you'd be wasting space on disk and in memory

4) the representation of data stored in CHAR (and VARCHAR) fields may be changed (usually change of character sets) by the DBMS on insert and on retrieval

5) PHP strings can contain binary data (including nulls) the PHP method of escaping the data may be mis-interpreted by the DBMS (see also 1)

Comment: thanks, regarding your second suggestion - but BLOB fields have upper limit as well, so there is a possibility for data loss as well, no?
regarding your third suggestion - I didn't mean specifically CHAR field, I meant text fields in general (CHAR, VARCHAR). So I may conclude that it's better to store serialized object in BLOB field because of the suggestion 4 and 5 that you mentioned.